# Java, if else что я делаю не так?

Tags: java, if, scanner

Дана задача: Вы являетесь администратором футбольного клуба и вам необходимо распределить по категориям уже завершенные игры на своем сайте.
Данная программа берет в качестве вводных 3 типа данных:

1. статус матча – проверяет, приостановлен ли матч или нет («true» - приостановлен, «false» – не приостановлен)
2. счет вашей команды
3. счет команды соперника.
   Завершите программу таким образом, что если матч приостановлен (1-ый вывод – «true»), то в результат выводится «Suspended».
   Если матч не приостановлен (1-й результат - «false»), то статусы должны устанавливаться в зависимости от результата матча: "Won", "Lost" или "Draw".

Пример вводных данных
false
3
2

Пример результата:
Won

Написал код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean isSuspended = read.nextBoolean();
       int ourScore = read.nextInt();
       int theirScore = read.nextInt();
       
       if (isSuspended == true) {
       System.out.println ("Suspended");
       } else {
           if (ourScore == theirScore) {
               System.out.println ("Draw");
           }
           if (ourScore > theirScore) {
               System.out.println ("Win");
           }
           if (theirScore > ourScore ) {
               System.out.println ("Lost");
           }
       }

       

   }
}
```

Код тестируется в программе Sololearn, программа подставляет значения и код должен выдавать правильный ответ.
4 из 5 тестовых данных выдают корректные результаты, но суть в том, что 2 варианта тестовых данных скрыты и я не могу посмотреть, при каких значениях код не работает. Где я ошибся?

Comment: Вы в примере ожидаете `Won`, а в коде возвращаете `Win`

Comment: Да, точно! Переправил на "won" и заработало... Ох

Answer (score 1):

Надо было переправить Win на Won и все заработало!